# Unable to access modules from custom Python package

Tags: python

I am trying to access custom package modules, but getting "module not found" error. Under the directory `

```
└── C:\PythonProg
       ├── Test.py
       └── PackageTest
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── mod1.py
            └── mod2.py
```

In `__init__.py`, I have:

```py
import mod1
import mod2
```

In `mod1.py`:

```py
def mult(x,y):
    print(x*y)
```

In `mod2.py`:

```py
def add(x,y):
    print(x,y)
```

In `Test.py`:

```py
import PackageTest as pt
   
pt.mod1.add(2,3)
pt.mod2.mult(1,2)
```

When executing `Test.py`, why is the error popping up again, saying "No Module Named `mod1`"?
I have tried many times, still facing same error.

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\PythonProg\PackageTest\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
 import mod1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `__init__.py` to look like this:

```
from . import mod1
from . import mod2
```

And fix your test.py to look like this... (you had them swapped):

```
import PackageTest as pt

pt.mod1.mult(2,3)
pt.mod2.add(1,2)
```

Comment: Also, for more info on relative imports, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/12818877)

Answer (score 0):

If the script you are wishing to import that is not in the current directory, you may want to take this approach:

make these changes in your test.py

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.', 'PackageTest')))
import mod1,mod2

mod2.add(2,3)
mod1.mult(1,2)
```